# Using #define to access App Delegate Object doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using App Delegate object in different classes. I want access it in whole project. Am define this object in Prefix.pch file as

```
#define Appdelegate (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

but problem is that Appdelegate variable does not access App delegate variable.
it Shows error.

but if am use this code works fine

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.variablename;
```

Am I doing it correct or is there a way of doing what I do?

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Should be:

```
#define Appdelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
//                  ^----------------------parenthesis--------------------------^
```

Comment: Yup. With your `#define`, doing `[Appdelegate variablename]` would work, but not `Appdelegate.variablename`. Because if you omit the outer parenthesis, the cast to `(AppDelegate *)` would be done on the whole expression, in this case your `variablename`.

Answer (score 1):

As this question and its answers demonstrate, leaning on the preprocessor is usually a bad idea.

1. It's easy to get things wrong. We all develop good instincts for operator precedence, but the preprocessor has no clue.  To defend against unexpected context problems, you often need to wrap everything in extra parens and braces.
2. It's easy to convince yourself that you're doing one thing when the code is doing another. When things break, neither the compiler's error messages nor the debugger are likely to help much.
3. Most important, the preprocessor can let you take a bad idea and spread it pervasively through the program.  The bad idea here is using the App Delegate globally.

Global variables are a code smell. Efforts to make global variables even more global by stuffing them into precompiled headers are a code smell.  If the framework thought you should have access to the AppDelegate from everywhere, you wouldn't need to jump through these (modest) hoops!

So, when tempted to do something like this, it's nice to know the preprocessor is there and the pch headers are there, but keep in mind that you're fighting the framework and almost certainly making a design error.  That might be OK in your context, but it's something to know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import AppDelegate file where you are declare delegate macro:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

And then define

```
#define Appdelegate (((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]))
```